# .Net Core 2 API How To Get Current Logged In User?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

This issue is trolling me quite hard at the moment. Never had a problem in Web API 2, now in Core, I can't get the current claims or identity for the user that is logged in.

When the app launches, the Index() IActionResult is called and the user is logged in with SignInAsync() method.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "CA19207"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Actor, "2770"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, "User")
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TNEVP");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

      var isIn = principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;//returns true
      var isAuthed = (HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).IsAuthenticated;//returns false

        return Ok();
    }
```

Then from my Angular 2 service, I make a call to api/user to get the claims for the logged in user. However the claim set is empty and the User is not authenticated.

```
    [HttpGet("claims")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> Get()
    {
        var claims = (User as ClaimsPrincipal).Claims;
        return await Task.FromResult(claims);
    }
```

The markup in Startup class is basic:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(o =>
            {
                o.LoginPath = "/api/login";
                o.LogoutPath = "/api/logout";
                // additional config options here
            });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });
    }
```

So what am I missing here? This should be a simple implementation to construct claims and then serve them back via API call. Thanks!~

***UPDATE***
I now have this working in Core 1.1, took about 30 minutes. I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong in Core 2.

Here's the code:
        Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            CookieName = "MyCookie",
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            LoginPath = "/Home/Login"
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }

     HomeController.cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn()
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Robert Lee"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "CA2770"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, "8-8-2018")
        };

        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "SessionClaim");

        var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync
        (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
         userPrincipal,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
                IsPersistent = false,
                AllowRefresh = false
            });

        return View();
    }

    SessionController.cs

    [HttpGet("claims", Name = "GetClaims")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetClaims()
    {
        var user = (User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        var claims = user.Claims;
        var isAuthed = user.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        return await Task.FromResult(claims);
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling this api from browser?

Comment: The api is called from an Angular Js service.

Comment: You need to send the cookies on the request... you can configure to each request or for all...

`this.http.get('http://...', { withCredentials: true })`

Comment: From Postman or Browser, the Core 2 version always returns local authority identity, not the one created in the Index method

Comment: I understand but, but angular is sending this?

Comment: Yes so an angular service makes that API call. I was sending cookies on the request HOWEVER, that was not the issue. I found that even though no documentation states this, one must set AuthenticationProperties as so: 

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, 
                    new AuthenticationProperties { ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), IsPersistent = true, AllowRefresh = false });

Now the API call works via Angular service and if I simply browse to the api method in a browser.